# How to set a specific return type to a method in Java

Tags: java, methods, return-type

So I have a class called Person

I can easily do something like

```
Person getPerson(){ return new Person(); }
```

But instead of using the 'Person' I want to declare my own class as a return type

```
Class<?> personClass = Class.forName("Person");
personClass getPerson() { return new Person(); }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is almost certainly wrong if you want to implement this, but yes, it's possible.

```
Object getThing(String className) throws Exception
{
    return Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

You'll have to cast the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Person` **class object** (I mean, `Class<Person>`), you can just use `Person.class` or `personInstance.getClass()`.

Also, if you want a custom method that will return it, then you can use:

```
public Class<Person> getPersonClass() {
    return Person.class;
}
```

But it is almost pointless, because you can just call `Person.class`. Beware, also, that `Person.class` is evaluated in compile time, and `Class.forName("...")` - in runtime.

Comment: I'm mainly look on a way to call getPerson() without using Person as a type but instead using a Class instance of Person.

Comment: Than Michael's answer should suit you nicely, isn't it?